# SQL query help - have two where conditons in join condition

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have these tables - Book (b), Trade (t), TradingDesk(d), CounterParty(c).

Trade (t) that has 2 columns Buyer, Seller it looks like

```
**Buyer** **Seller**
B456  B222 
C55   B222 
B323  C4333
```

I would have to join these with Book(b) based on the value present in Buyer and Seller columns. ie, if the values starts with 'B' should check in Books table if that id exists e.g : For B456 - should be checked with Books table for id 456.

I wrote the following that can do this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.Name, t.Buyer, t.Seller FROM  Book AS b
  INNER JOIN TradingDesk AS d  ON b.TradingDeskId = d.Id
    Join Trade as t 
       on  substring(t.Seller,2,len(t.Seller)) = cast(b.Id as varchar)
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT d.Name , t.Buyer, t.Seller FROM  Book AS b 
  INNER JOIN TradingDesk AS d ON b.TradingDeskId = d.Id
    Join Trade as t 
       on substring(t.Buyer,2,len(t.Buyer)) = cast(b.Id as varchar)
```

Now, I need to check values starting with 'C' with CounterParty(c) table. I tried adding a where condition to the join but this doesnt work and gives a error in where statement.
I tried tweaking the join condition with where conditions:

```
on  substring(t.Seller,2,len(t.Seller)) = cast(b.Id as varchar) where t.Seller like 'B%' 
 AND
substring(t.Seller,2,len(t.Seller)) = cast(c.partyId as varchar) where t.Seller like 'C%'
```

But seems I cannot have two conditions framed in the ON part  with multiple where conditions.

Any way of achieving  this ?

Thanks
Mani

Comment: Your table design is flawed. Could you change it? And post your full query plus error.

Comment: You **can** have several conditions in the `ON` clause but `WHERE` does not belong to the ON clause.

Comment: posted the query more clearly as a separate question at http://stackoverflow.com/q/6735334/849917. I leave this one open if any one can fix it in the same way as what I attempted to.

Comment: Can you explain what a CounterParty is?  From your design it seems like you are representing trades between two items, each of which can be either a book or something called a "CounterParty"

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to LEFT JOIN, then put the additional condition(s) there

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.Name, t.Buyer, t.Seller FROM  Book AS b
  LEFT JOIN TradingDesk AS d  ON b.TradingDeskId = d.Id
    LEFT Join Trade as t 
       on  substring(t.Seller,2,len(t.Seller)) = cast(b.Id as varchar)

       AND t.Seller like 'B%' -- put your additional condition(s) here

UNION
SELECT DISTINCT d.Name , t.Buyer, t.Seller FROM  Book AS b 
  LEFT JOIN TradingDesk AS d ON b.TradingDeskId = d.Id
    LEFT Join Trade as t 
       on substring(t.Buyer,2,len(t.Buyer)) = cast(b.Id as varchar)
```

Comment: yes it helps. But still could not get what I need from this. Have posted another link at http://stackoverflow.com/q/6735334/849917 to explain this differently.

Answer (score 0):

The following query is most probably sub-optimal, but it should give you the necessary result and thus, at least, provide you with a starting point:

```
SELECT
  d.Name,
  t.Buyer,
  t.Seller
FROM (
  SELECT
    'B' AS Prefix,
    COUNT(Id AS varchar(20)) AS Id,
    TradingDeskId
  FROM Book
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'C' AS Prefix,
    COUNT(Id AS varchar(20)) AS Id,
    TradingDeskId
  FROM CounterParty
) bc
  INNER JOIN TradingDesk d ON d.Id = bc.TradingDeskId
  INNER JOIN Trade t ON bc.Prefix + bc.Id IN (t.Buyer, t.Seller)
```

Comment: I am trying to explore this Andiry. But, I need b.Name from Books table. As I mentioned, I have 4 tables. Book, TradingDesk, Trade and CounterParty. Book needs to be joined with TradingDesk to get the tradinig desk name and the matching books list and this should be used for checking. CounerParties can be directly used. Can you please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/q/6735334/849917 as well where I have put my latest development with this. Thank you.

Comment: Two Corrections : (1) I guess u meant CAST inestead of COUNT. (2) In the second select statement, the CounterParty doesnt have a tradingdeskid column. So, that is a problem.

Comment: @Mani: Your newer question contains a slightly different (albeit closely resembling) schema, so I should rather continue paying attention to this problem in general there, when (and if) it is re-opened. As for this answer, I'll wait for some reasonable time and then most probably delete it. Thanks for pointing out the discrepancies about this answer, anyway. It was really silly of me to put COUNT in place of CAST.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it something like this (untested):

```
select 
  t.Buyer, 
  t.Seller, 
  case when t.Buyer like 'B%' THEN (select BookName from Book where BookId = t.Buyer)
                              ELSE (select CpName from Counterparty where CPId = t.Buyer)
  end BuyerName,
  case when t.Seller like 'B%' THEN (select BookName from Book where BookId = t.Seller)
                               ELSE (select CpName from Counterparty where CPId = t.Seller)
  end SellerName
from 
  Trade t
```

The problem you have is that, since the table you want to join to is data driven, you can't specify it in the FROM clause..