# SQL Query Help - Joining Multiple Columns Based On Condition

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL query help - have two where conditons in join condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732588/sql-query-help-have-two-where-conditons-in-join-condition)

I have the following tables with the columns as below. I have mentioned what I need from this. I already posted a link in here [SQL query help - have two where conditons in join condition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6732588/849917) with what I have been trying but cannot get this through. Once again positing it plainly with what I need:

```
Book
BookId, BookName

Desk
DeskId, BookId ,DeskName

CounterParty
CPId, CpName

Trade
TradeId, Buyer, Seller
```

This is how the Buyer and Seller data would be :

```
Buyer Seller
B3232  B323
C32    B222
B323   C323
```

Based on the starting character B or C in these two columns, I need to join Book or CP table to check the ids.

```
I need **t.TradingDeskName, b.BookName, c.CpName, t.Buyer, t.Seller.**
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks,
mani

p.s : I am trying to get this done through SQL or Linq to Sql.

---

The recent query but have more to fix :

```
SELECT DISTINCT desk.Name as TradingDeskName, b.Name as Book, t.Seller, t.Buyer, c.PartyName, FROM TradingDesk AS desk 

 RIGHT JOIN Book as b
    ON  b.TradingDeskId = d.Id
 RIGHT JOIN Trade as t  
    ON LEFT(t.Buyer, 1) = 'B' AND SUBSTRING(t.Buyer, 2, len(t.Buyer)) = b.Id
 LEFT JOIN Book as b1 
    ON LEFT(t.Seller, 1) = 'B' AND SUBSTRING(t.Seller, 2, len(t.Seller)) = b1.Id 
 LEFT JOIN CounterParty as c 
    ON LEFT(t.Buyer, 1) = 'C' AND SUBSTRING(t.Buyer, 2, len(t.Buyer)) = c.PartyId 
 LEFT JOIN CounterParty as c1 
    ON LEFT(t.Seller, 1) = 'C' AND SUBSTRING(t.Seller, 2, len(t.Seller)) = c1.PartyId
```

As I mentioned I need :
**Desk.Name - B.Name - T.Seller - T.Buyer- C.PartyName**

The C.PartyName will have the value if T.Seller or T.Buyer value is starting with 'C' (from CounterParty Table) else will be null.

With the above query, I have null values coming in Desk.Name, B.Name and the logic of gettig C.PartyName is also not working.

---

Comment: I have given a link in here for the other question. Once I am able to figure out a answer, I shall post the same there and link the two.

Comment: but you have now created a duplicate post of the same question.  As I said you should edit your original post with the corrected question.

Comment: According to your data sample, both `Buyer` and `Seller` can be books. Which one then will `b.Name` in your query be based on?

Comment: Book will have to be joined with t.desks and then joined with trade. B.Name will be a union based on buyer and seller and then distinct of those will be taken.

Comment: @Mani: Do you mean that the same `Trade` will be represented twice in the output, once with the `Buyer` book name and once with the `Seller` book name, and with empty (NULL) `CounterParty` name both times?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways I could think of for achieving the desired results but because first things should come first, I'd suggest to modify the DB design if it is at all possible.

So, here are the 2 queries that I could work out:

**Query 1**

```
SELECT `t`.*,
(CASE 
    WHEN LEFT(`t`.`Buyer`, 1) = 'B' THEN
        (SELECT `b`.`BookName`
         FROM `Book` `b`
         WHERE `b`.`BookId` = SUBSTRING(`t`.`Buyer`, 2))
    ELSE (SELECT `c`.`CPName`
          FROM `CounterParty` `c`
          WHERE `c`.`CPId` = SUBSTRING(`t`.`Buyer`, 2))
END) AS `buyer_name`,
(CASE
    WHEN LEFT(`t`.`Seller`, 1) = 'B' THEN
        (SELECT `b`.`BookName`
         FROM `Book` `b`
         WHERE `b`.`BookId` = SUBSTRING(`t`.`Seller`, 2))
    ELSE (SELECT `c`.`CPName`
          FROM `CounterParty` `c`
          WHERE `c`.`CPId` = SUBSTRING(`t`.`Seller`, 2))
END) AS `seller_name`
FROM `Trade` `t`
```

**Query 2**

```
SELECT *
FROM `Trade` `t`
LEFT JOIN `Book` `b` ON LEFT(`t`.`Buyer`, 1) = 'B' AND SUBSTRING(`t`.`Buyer`, 2) = `b`.`BookId`
LEFT JOIN `Book` `b1` ON LEFT(`t`.`Seller`, 1) = 'B' AND SUBSTRING(`t`.`Seller`, 2) = `b1`.`BookId`
LEFT JOIN `CounterParty` `c` ON LEFT(`t`.`Buyer`, 1) = 'C' AND SUBSTRING(`t`.`Buyer`, 2) = `c`.`CPId`
LEFT JOIN `CounterParty` `c1` ON LEFT(`t`.`Seller`, 1) = 'C' AND SUBSTRING(`t`.`Seller`, 2) = `c1`.`CPId`;
```

Both the above queries return same results but in different formats. Please try and see which one works best for you.

Also, it isn't very clear from your question where does the table `Desk` fit in and what relations does it hold with other tables. Please feel free to add respective columns you'll need from `Desk`.

Please note that the suggested queries are in MySQL. It is not very clear what system are you running - you've mentioned in your post that you are trying using SQL or Linq SQL and in the tags you've mentioned everything + MySQL.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt. I am trying this in SQL. The Book is joined with the trading desk first and then the resulting Books are only used for further joins. Will try to convert to SQL and see if it works.

Comment: Could you pls leme know What is the LEFT operator do here ..

Comment: @Mani, the LEFT JOIN returns all rows from the left table (Trade in this example) and only matching rows from the right table (Book or CounterParty); for non-matching rows in the right table, it returns NULL. This is unlike INNER JOIN where only matching rows are returned from both the left and right tables.

You may like to read more here - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

In this particular example, a LEFT JOIN makes more sense because it is not known if there will always be a matching row-set.

Comment: Thanks. I meant the LEFT key word in the first sample. Just learnt, it is MYSQL syntax for substring again..

Comment: Aha! I didn't realize you were referring to the LEFT() function. Yes it's like substring but a little more simple and direct

Comment: So far thanks Abhay. I have edited to put the updated query that I have taken from you. But still it is not giving values in the way, I would have liked it. Any help with the updated format will be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it something like this (untested):

```
select 
  t.Buyer, 
  t.Seller, 
  case when t.Buyer like 'B%' THEN (select BookName from Book where BookId = t.Buyer)
                              ELSE (select CpName from Counterparty where CPId = t.Buyer)
  end BuyerName,
  case when t.Buyer like 'B%' THEN (select DeskName from Desk where BookId = t.Buyer)
                              ELSE NULL
  end BuyerDeskName,
  case when t.Seller like 'B%' THEN (select BookName from Book where BookId = t.Seller)
                               ELSE (select CpName from Counterparty where CPId = t.Seller)
  end SellerName,
  case when t.Seller like 'B%' THEN (select DeskName from Desk where BookId = t.Seller)
                               ELSE NULL
  end SellerDeskName,
from 
  Trade t
```

The problem you have is that, since the table you want to join to is data driven, you can't specify it in the FROM clause..

Comment: I get an error : Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Comment: are BookId and CPId primary keys? Also, try removing the BuyerDeskName/SellerDeskName subqueries, does that give the same result?

Comment: Yes steve they are. I tried the other as well, seems it needs some more tweak. I am just stuck being new to SQL..

Comment: What do you mean it needs more tweak?? Is the error message the same? You need to be more descriptive or its very hard to help you!

Comment: Thank you so far. Have edited the post with an update query. But still issue persists for some values.